# ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND and __thread in DLLs

Tags: dll, mingw-w64, thread-local-storage

I compile DLLs with MinGW64's gcc and clang, but unlike when I build them with MSVC those DLLs do not load with `LoadLibraryW()`, it reports the error 126 `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. I narrowed it down to my use in code of declarations of file scope variables such as `__thread uint8_t *array_to_order;`.

I can't imagine why thread local storage could cause the DLL to fail to load, any ideas?